# Should we allow people to offer help via outside communications like TeamViewer?

Tags: discussion

I've come across a user that I've seen on several occasions offer to assist others via [TeamViewer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeamViewer). He will ask them to provide their ID and password. It appears that the user is positively trying to help and not attempting anything nefarious, but I have some concerns about this:

1. Sharing your screen with a stranger can be risky. Obviously we're not everyone's computer nanny, but we do have a lot of inexperienced programmers that don't seem like they're as security conscious as they should be.
2. If they find a conclusion via outside services, they may not bother actually posting a decent question and answer here on Stack Overflow. This means it won't help others, and it won't help users learn to ask a good question (provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), etc.).
3. It's been a while since I've used TeamViewer, but I'm pretty sure if you want to share your screen with someone, it will generate you a code that you can send someone. You should never give someone your password, as that might allow them to log into your PC whenever they want to.

Some examples:

[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34125892/how-to-get-the-latest-row-from-database-when-id-is-guid#comment56000623_34125892)
[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34020260/how-to-set-resource-key-to-anchor-href-tag-on-aspx-page-in-asp-net-localization/34033072#comment55873629_34033072)
[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34058771/getting-the-values-from-previouspage-findcontrol/34059258#comment55873528_34059258)
[4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34020260/how-to-set-resource-key-to-anchor-href-tag-on-aspx-page-in-asp-net-localization/34033072#comment55840499_34033072)
[5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34008940/asp-net-connection-with-oracle-db/34011747#comment55794136_34011747)
[6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33925549/how-to-access-html5-audio-play-event-in-codebehind-asp-net-with-c-sharp/33929252#comment55691016_33929252)
[7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33873726/sqldatareader-returning-0-rows-on-chrome-but-returns-1-row-on-ie-firefox/33884149#comment55546746_33884149)
[8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33851413/read-from-2-sql-datasource-in-asp-net/33852027#comment55468341_33852027)
[9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33691141/the-resource-cannot-be-found-requested-url-login-aspx/33691413#comment55156222_33691413)
[10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33691279/binding-events-onclick-on-bootstrap-buttons-in-asp-net/33691330#comment55155164_33691330)
[11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33665067/adding-a-select-all-in-drop-down-list/33665402#comment55145862_33665402)

An example comment looks like this:

> It is too many questions about that, and we can't understand each other exactly... Download TeamViewer and let me know your ID and password, I will connect to your computer and help you to solve the problem. My email is ***@gmail.com

Should we discourage this kind of behavior?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this user doesn't really mean their *TeamViewer account password* but indeed the code that you mention, but [damn](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PoorCommunicationKills).

Comment: @BoltClock You're probably right, but will a TeamViewer novice know that? I hope so, but I wouldn't count on it.

Comment: Yeah the phrasing's just incredibly unfortunate.

Comment: I'm not personally comfortable with the notion; I mean sure, it's their time and energy they're investing, but I don't want that to become something that's just "okay" in these parts.

Comment: I completely discourage that sort of thing on SU, especially if there's not going to be any follow up on site. We do occationally do remote help on chat, but usually between *trusted* users

Comment: Love the subject matter but completely disagree that anyone should be using SO to bolster confidence in accepting otherwise anonymous remote desktopping.

Comment: The examples are all from the same user. Perhaps a mod (@BoltClock?) could have a word with him?

Comment: [Here's a quick query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/404699) that returns comments containing his email.

Comment: Isn't it better to reverse the idea? If someone knows how to do it, let them record their screen and allow them to attach it to the answer. Maybe even live (voice?) chat and laser pointer for the asker?

Comment: @ThisNameBetterBeAvailable That doesn't address the security issues that have been raised. If someone wants to do live or pre-recorded debugging sessions, that's great. But as Stack Overflow currently exists, we don't have a mechanism for people to share videos.

Comment: @mason i would agree that suggesting to the asker to allow other people to look at (or even control!) their monitors is a step too far. Also, team-viewer's license for non-commercial purposes may be indirectly violated if teamviewer is used because the asker may be asking help for a project in the company he/she works.

Comment: @ThisNameBetterBeAvailable: That's not generally what "non-commercial" means; it means *you don't sell a service that includes using Team-Viewer*.

Comment: @NathanTuggy i know. But i don't know how teamviewer views this issue.

Comment: @NathanTuggy It's a [violation of Team Viewers license](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/help/213-How-exactly-is-private-use-defined) to use the free version without paying for it when the use is commercial. Thus, if someone was asking for help with a problem at work, and used Team Viewer's free version, that would be a license violation. It would not be a violation to ask for help with homework. Not that I think we should take it upon ourselves to be Team Viewer's license enforcement.

Comment: @mason: Ah. It doesn't look like they use the term "commercial" for that, probably for the reason I gave.

Comment: I *used* to offer programming help via email, but I stopped that last week due to being contacted by a user accusing me of downvoting their question (which was at -6) and asking me to remove my downvote.

Comment: Yea, usually, it's a bad idea to give out your personal contact details on sites like these. Unless you like being someone's personal go-to person for _any and all_ issues...

Comment: I don't think about terms and conditions or whatever legal stuff, It is just not safe and It doesnt help anyone, a developer seeking help via teamviewer should reconsider how is he/she researches, it is just not the way

Answer (score 143):

### No.

We (SO) should *not encourage* it, as such sessions are of *no* value to future visitors.
If 2 users want to start a discussion about any subject, SO's chat can be used.

Personally, I'd actively discourage screen sharing, since there's no telling what the other party may want to do.

Your [second example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34020260/how-to-set-resource-key-to-anchor-href-tag-on-aspx-page-in-asp-net-localization/34033072#comment55873629_34033072):

> - *"third party softwares cannot be installed on my machine..."* – OP
> - *"@OP in that case download Ammy Admin. You will not install that, it is executable program. And let me know just ID, there is no password. You will have to confirm"* – Other party.

In this case, the "No third party software" restriction was probably placed on the OP's machine for good reason. We should try to make users aware of the risks involved with screen sharing. Or at very least discourage it.

Comment: Emphatically agree. Maybe change that to **HELL NO!**. As soon as word gets out that this is being practiced you can count on [this](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_xp-security/phone-call-from-windows-is-this-a-scam/1164b6ee-e441-41bf-b210-2e293cab96c5) happening. btw, I've broached this with the Team Viewer security team; they could care less.

Comment: Yea, this isn't something TeamViewer can, or even should handle (Aside from the unfortunate "password" naming, perhaps)

Comment: Have a "Great Answer"-badge.

Comment: I didn't quite see that coming. Nice.

Comment: @Jeeped and why should they? They provide a great tool for no cost to home user, I think they've done enough of caring already, you can hardly demand for more. It's up to each and every person to care about their own security.

Comment: @zespri - tbh, I flip-flop between a mindset that believes it is good for all concerned if neophytes are coddled to some extent and the more Darwinian 'guns don't kill people, people kill people'. No, it's not Team Viewer's **fault** that their software is widely used for nefarious purposes but you might think that any software company with a modicum of social conscience would make some effort toward discouraging said practices. They don't and I'm disappointed in that. 'nuff said ... this is going off-topic even for a comment.

Comment: Ok, so we should not encourage it, it should in fact be discouraged. That raises the natural next question: How? Should this kind of invites be formally forbidden? Should people  who send them be contacted by a moderator and asked to stop? Should we just leave it  to whoever happens to pass by to leave a discouraging comment?

Comment: Imo, a comment pointing out that it's not recommended should be enough. If the user does it often, you can also flag it, so a mod can have a chat with him. (you may want to link to other examples, or even to this meta post)

Comment: My intention was that this meta post would serve as a way to gather the community consensus and to be something we can link back to if we see this behavior going forward. Moderators have already cleaned up the examples I linked to.

Answer (score 29):

Hell no. There are three big things wrong here:

1. Taking the conversation outside Stack Overflow obviously defeats the purpose of Stack Overflow, as discussed above.
2. TeamViewer is way too powerful for the job. It's not just screensharing, but actual remote operation of the desktop. No way should we encourage newbies to open up that kind of access to a stranger. Obviously.
3. The user is actually requesting the username and password, not just the connection ID (as discussed above).