# Is it OK to offer a user help on another platform?

Tags: discussion, support, comments

I've seen many comment sections on answers in the [discord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discord.js) tag, where either the answerer or OP asks if they can talk on Discord. Since they are making Discord bots, I assume they would all have Discord accounts. I don't really know if this is fine or not for multiple reasons:

- This fills up some comment sections with people putting usernames
- They can still get help on Stack Overflow
- The goal of Stack Overflow is apparently to build a knowledge base, but we can't see it from a user's Discord DMs
- This leads to more short, low quality answers that ask the user to get more information in Discord

Should I flag these comments as not needed? Or should I just leave them there?

Comment: The flag name is "no longer needed". And that seems pretty accurate to me for such comments, they have a shelf-life of exactly one yes or no reply.

Comment: Related, if not even a duplicate: [Should we allow people to offer help via outside communications like TeamViewer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311869/should-we-allow-people-to-offer-help-via-outside-communications-like-teamviewer)

Comment: I, personally, agree with the answer in the linked answer in @BDL 's comment. If the OP can't clarify the question in their question it's off-topic as it's unclear or lacks debugging details. If they then solve the problem and don't both improve their question and provide a detailed answer, then the question isn't useful and no one else can consume the answer; prompting downvotes for people with similar problems in the future. If the OP doesn't want to take the time to make their question clear, then vote to close it; don't migrate to Discord.

Comment: [Your comment on yivi's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415812/is-it-ok-to-offer-a-user-help-on-another-platform#comment893456_415813) says "What I'm looking at is a downvoted answer." but the question seems to talk primarily about comments. Which of these are you asking about?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I'm talking about the comment sections in answers

Comment: *"I'm talking about the comment sections in answers"* Then you should be clear about that in *your* question, @MrMythical .

Comment: @MrMythical And did the answer actually answer the problem? I could well see the answer being downvoted because it failed to solve the problem, *and* an answer-comment offering help because it failed to solve the problem – that doesn't mean it was downvoted because of offering help.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi after double checking this question, it seems that this was a typo, which is probably why the answer was downvoted. This question however does not apply to only 1 question/answer, but I was using that as an example

Answer (score 31, accepted):

What you ask in the title of the question and what you ask in the body are different things:

> Is it OK to offer a user help on another platform?

If it's not spammy, sometimes there can be value in directing users to different platforms.

Sometimes the help they need can be gotten elswhere, and this is not the right platform for the type of question they want to ask, or simply there are other venues where **additional** discussion on a topic could be had that goes beyond that what's fit to have on Stack Overflow.

I've seen comments like this, and they were fine, making users aware of other options or places to have the type of conversation we don't want to have here can be good for everyone.

> Should I flag these comments as not needed? Or should I just leave them there?

Flag away, of course. These comments are no longer needed to improve or clarify the post, and just noise for future visitors. They should be deleted.

Comment: I disagree that offering help on another platform is OK. If the question needs off-site interactions, then it should be closed on SO. It might be ok to close-vote and then point the user to another community, but leaving the question open while answering it outside of SO is counter productive.

Comment: The question can be closed **and** the user can be directed elsewhere. Those things are not in contradiction. I haven't said anything in my answer about voting to close or not, simply because this question is not about that.

Comment: Your answer reads as if it would be ok to direct users elsewhere while leaving the question open. That's the thing I disagree with. Either leave open and don't redirect or close and redirect.

Comment: I don't know why you read my answer like that. I'm a bit confused. The question does not mention closure or topicality, and neither does my answer. These are  orthogonal issues.

Comment: Exactly, it doesn't mention closure or topicality. That's the problem! It should better be written like: "For questions that can't be answered on SO, sometimes there can be value in directing users to different platforms. Sometimes the help they need can be gotten elswhere, and this is not the right platform for the type of question they want to ask. In this case, close-voting the question and redirecting the user to another resource may help".

Comment: What I'm looking at is a downvoted _answer_. The OP sends some code in the comments, then the answerer asks for the OP to friend them on Discord. I don't really want to share a link, so I can prevent the meta effect. The question is fine, also has 2 upvotes.

Comment: @BDL, if you want to post another question that says whatever you want, go ahead. I think the OP posted a perfectly reasonable question (or questions, once one gets past the problem with the different questions on title vs body). These comments can be posted on off-topic questions, on on-topic questions, or even on answers. I've seen them.

Comment: I wouldn't say you are saying it's ok to leave the question ok, @yivi , however, I would suggest (like I did in my comment) that if you are suggest that the question should be asked else where that that implies that the question isn't on-topic for [main] and so you probably should at least mention that.

Comment: You should have made that very clear in your question. Those comments should just be flagged as No longer needed. [so] isn't a support site.

Comment: @Larnu As I mentioned earlier, these comments can be left not only on off-topic questions, but can be left on on-topic questions (e.g. to suggest further discussion elsewhere beyond what SO accomodates), or even on answers. The meta question does not say anywhere of what kind of post is it involved.

Comment: I haven't posted a question, @Larnu. And again, no need to make it explicity if the comments where posted on a question or an answer. It's the same thing. Because this is about the comments, not about the posts themselves.

Comment: That was aimed at the OP's [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415812/is-it-ok-to-offer-a-user-help-on-another-platform#comment893456_415813), @yivi . I'm aware you are not the OP here... Yivi <> MrMythical (Unless MrMythical is a sock puppet of yours?)

Comment: @Larnu Since you posted the comment under my answer, and comments usually address the post they are written under, and you haven't tagged anyone else in it, I'm sure you can understand my confusion.

Comment: I think you did a great job of separating concerns in this answer. If users want to use other platforms to work out a problem, so be it– we don't gain anything by blocking that in a meaningful way (unless, as you mentioned, it's spammy in some way). But regardless, we should work to maintain the quality of content on _our_ platform like normal, which means flagging conversational comments as NLN, and downvoting/ closing/ deleting posts that are not useful.

Answer (score 11):

To answer the question literally, yes flag these comments as No Longer Needed; they are conversational which isn't what the comments are for. If the users *really* want to have a conversation on Stack Overflow, we have chat.

---

Now, to answer the broader subject of are such comments "ok" at all. They aren't specifically not allowed; if the OP and answerer want to migrate to a different channel they are free to do so. The problem for Stack Overflow, however, is that the usefulness of the question and answer could easily be depleted by this. If a question is answered off site, due to it (the question) being unclear or incomplete then it's not going to be useful/helpful to future readers. The same is true for the answer; if it isn't a complete answer on its own it's not going to be useful/helpful to future readers.

As such, if you are visiting the question later, you may well feel inclined to downvote the posts and/or vote to close the question as unclear; as the problem was not clearly defined.

Ideally, if users do migrate to a different channel, it should be in chat on the site as at least the conversational can be accessed without using a different site. They should also be using the edit feature to improve their question and answer after the discussion. If the answer resulted in more question(s) then the OP should be posting new questions, so that users in the future can find all the useful information, and likely the questions should be linked.

Don't forget, as well, that Stack Overflow is *not* a consultancy service, it's a Q&A site. The users here are *not* expected to support the user after they give an answer. If the user gets the answer they need, however, lacks the skills to implement or understand it, that (with all due respect to them) isn't the answerer's problem. It is up to the user using the answer to ensure they take the time to understand the answers they get; Stack Overflow isn't a tutorial site.

Only you, however, can judge if the question and/or answer is useful/helpful or not and if the question should remain open; they are your votes, and we can't tell you what you to do with them.

Comment: I will add on to this, that if you are the one requesting that someone have a discussion with you on a different service, do it as a last resort rather than as the first step. In the cases where I've done it, it meant taking them to that service's Slack to get missing information in a more casual way than what's suitable here (because that's what they were comfortable with). Once you've gotten any information that needed a little clarity/guidance to get, get the asker to update their question on StackOverflow, you answer it as applicable and then clean up your own "no longer needed" comments.

Answer (score -1):

> Is it OK to offer help on another platform?

Yes...

Provided the right context as there's a few different scenarios:

**Option 1: The question isn't really right for Stack Overflow in the first place**

In this scenario it's best to flag the question, or downvote it/vote to close it (depending on what privileges you have). There's nothing saying that you can't point them in the right direction when you do this.

**Option 2: The question is valid for Stack Overflow, but the questioner feels they need more support beyond the answer**

If the answerer feels comfortable in doing so, then there's nothing stopping them from providing extra support over something like Discord. In this scenario, the question and answer should be updated once the proper solution is found.

**Option 3: The question topic is valid for Stack Overflow, but the question simply lacks proper detail to give a reasonable answer**

Again, there's nothing stopping people from hooking up on Discord to help each other... BUT, the question should either be closed or updated with the necessary details to post a reasonable answer.

> Should I downvote/flag the comments in question?

Yes, these comments provide unnecessary clutter - I'd argue they shouldn't have even been comments in the first place (especially those giving out usernames), they should have been Direct Messages between the two users.

Additionally, if the question/answer is in a state where it isn't particularly clear or useful; then feel free to downvote them too.

**In Summary**

If you feel like a user would be better helped elsewhere, feel free to point them that way. For instance, if the questioner is an absolute beginner who has no handle on code whatsoever, as long as you answer the question at hand, providing links to something like CodeAcademy will genuinely help the questioner.

If the questioner doesn't know how to dig up the extra information needed for you to form a reasonable answer, then it's up to you whether or not you connect on another platform to help them form the question and then answer it.

Similarly, it might be that the questioner has a few questions that seem connected - rather than answering individually it might make sense to take a closer look at their codebase. Fixing one issue, might resolve the others; in which case one question can be expanded with the relevant information, and properly answered.

In ALL cases, if the question/answer/comment isn't something that might prove useful to other users then downvote/flag accordingly.

Comment: *"If you feel like a user would be better helped elsewhere, feel free to point them that way"* - Stack Overflow is not a help desk, it's meant to be a "knowledge base"

Comment: @MrMythical, you're right; it's meant to be a knowledge base; but pointing people to a more relevant place when they ask more "help desk" style questions isn't detrimental, and actually serves to remind people that "actually, this ain't the place for that" and should hopefully make the questioner think twice before asking that style of question again.

Answer (score -7):

> Is it OK to offer a user help on another platform?

Asking users to switch to another platform for help is in general not accepted on SO.

If the question is ill suited for SO in first place, it might make sense to close the question and point in a comment to another venue where it may be on-topic. But on on-topic and answerable questions, comments like this are not a good idea.

> Should I flag these comments as not needed? Or should I just leave them there?

Yes, definitely flag them. They should be deleted.

> What I'm looking at is a downvoted answer

Posting anything else than a direct answer in the answer box is not allowed. If you encounter answers that don't answer the question and point to some other site, downvote them and flag them as "not an answer".

Comment: If a person asks a question about extending a WordPress plugin that has say 10 downloads, the question may technically be on topic, but I would tell them to go to the WordPress support forums for that particular plugin so they can get help from the developer of the plugin as no one on Stack Overflow is going to know how to help them.

Comment: Do you have specific evidence that asking / suggesting that users switch to a different platform is "in general not accepted" on SO?  My experience is the opposite.