# Is it good thing to ask for Git links of code and try to run it to give a correct answer? Is it that worth it to get reputation?

Tags: discussion

If some developer asks a question with relevant code, and if we couldn't able to figure out the issue in code, is it okay to ask them to provide Git links of the project or a Git link of a minimal reproducible example so that we can try it, figure out the issue and post the answer to Git as an accepted answer? Is it that worth it to spend time to get some reputation?

The reason I asked is that when I tried to answer in comments a user opened a chat room. So I asked for a Git link. He asked for my [Telegram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telegram_(software)) or Facebook contact, I haven’t responded yet.

Comment: For SO to work as a Q&A site, questions and answers must be self-contained.  Use of off-site resources to show code (e.g. git) or communicate (FB, Telegram etc) undermine the site's mission; they should be avoided.

Comment: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428)

Comment: By "Git", do you mean [GitHub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub) (or similar, like [GitLab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitLab))?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Git can also mean the plain and simple command-line version without any fancy GitHub account hoo-haa

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're asking the wrong question.

The relevant issue isn't, "is it worth to spend time to get some reputation?" but rather, "will the question and answer, as presented, be helpful to future visitors?". If it requires an off-site code repository to answer well, then the likelihood of the Q&A being helpful to the site is lowered greatly. Much better to ask them to create and post a valid [Minimal Runnable Example program](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), one that is small enough so that the code can be posted in the question as code-formatted text.

Regarding your addition:

> The reason I asked is that when I tried to answer in comments a user opened a chat room. So I asked for a git link. He asked for my telegram or facebook contact, I havent responded yet.

It is certainly reasonable to use chat to ask for question clarification and code, and I have used this to coach a new user through the steps in their creating a decent MRE (although this can be very time consuming and not always worth it). It is usually not best for the original poster to ask for help outside of this site, especially if they are trying to use the site as a personal help site, something which it most definitely is not, since doing so, can cheat the site out of a better question and possibly better answers for future visitors (which ***is*** the main purpose of this site).

See [Is it OK to offer a user help on another platform?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415812/is-it-ok-to-offer-a-user-help-on-another-platform) for some of the nuances on this.

Comment: Could you please check the updated question with about the reason I asked this?

Comment: @GowthamKK: please see edit to my answer

Comment: Thanks. I should have avoided asking this question . I regret  for my invalid question.

Comment: @GowthamKK: no. There is nothing invalid about your question at all, and better to ask it than not. You have lost no reputation from this meta question, and the site gains some information from it.

Comment: @GowthamKK: please see the [Voting on Meta](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta#:~:text=Votes%20on%20meta%20do%20not,reputation%20to%20participate%20on%20meta.) link in case you are confused with how meta voting works and how it can mean different things from the [main] main site.

Comment: Thanks for this info. I also had the doubt that I  saw meta and main state have unsync reputation count. Got it cleared now.

Comment: @GowthamKK: on further exploration, I have modified my answer. Please see the changes and the link.

Answer (score 9):

Code should be in the question, not just available via a  link. The same applies for answers.

So sure, ask for a minimum reproducable example if the question needs it but not as a link.

Links can rot, the code they show can change, the linked site may go away or change location, all with no real way for us to check that the question or answer still make sense.

Only you can judge whether you think it's worth it to try to clarify a question or whether to move on to a different question that's already clear and answer that instead. Wasting time on something when you could be doing something more worthwhile instead is called [Opportunity cost](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/o/opportunitycost.asp)